# Quickblox for Nativescript Angular

Tags: nativescript, quickblox, nativescript-angular

Does anybody know if I can use Quickblox for my Nativescript (Angular) app. I would like have video calls integrated in my application.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin for Quickblox yet. You might have to write one. You will have to refer [marshalling native to JS code](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) first, then [start with your plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins), use Quickblox native APIs.

Comment: QuickBlox Native script SDK is currently in development.
At the moment for cross-platform development you can use [QuickBlox React Native SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/react-native-quick-start) or [QuickBlox Flutter SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-quick-start)